# How to find the duration between 2 Instant timestamp

Tags: java, timestamp

I am trying to show the timestamp when the program first start and the time when it stops.
Then I need to find the duration time between the beginning and end.
All of the above information need to be printed

But I have trouble distinguishing between the two Instant time (beginning, end) in my code.
Here is what I have, I know I should not be using null but you get the idea.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length == 0) {
        Instant t1 = null;
        Instant t2 = null;
        Duration duration = null;
        System.out.println(t1.now());
        System.out.println("Input data is missing. Expecting player data.");
        System.out.println(t2.now());
        System.out.println(duration.between(t1, t2));
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

Comment: Let me guess, you have `NullPointerException` on `System.out.println(t1.now());`

Comment: You should really start initializing your objets with something else than `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting `NullPointerException` because `now()` is a static in `Instant` while you are using it with object of `Instant`. Also there is no need to declare an object of `Duration` class because again `between()` is static to `Duration` class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
if (args.length == 0) {
    Instant t1, t2;
    t1 = Instant.now();
    System.out.println(t1);
    System.out.println("Input data is missing. Expecting player data.");
    t2 = Instant.now();
    System.out.println(t2);
    System.out.println(Duration.between(t1, t2));
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.